# Call without arguments

Tags: angular, typescript

just found a code snippet like this:

```
  validate(formControl: FormControl){
    const isValid = true;
    return isValid ? null : {
      emailValid: {
        valid: true
      }
    };   }

  validateData() {
    return  [
      {value: this.validate, errorMsg: "error" }
    ];   }
```

I didn't understand what is (conceptually) the call `this.validate` after `value:`, it's called without the () and is correctly executed.
If i put a `console.log(formControl.value)` in `validate` I get the correct value data.

If I use `value: this.validate()` I obviously get the error about the missing argument.

What I'd like to do is pass another argument, ie: `validate(formControl: FormControl, user: string){}` and i get the missing argument error.

There's a way to get the formControl like in the `value: this.validate` and at the same time pass the argument?

Already tried to store the data in a global var but the item is initialized before population.

Thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend the author of that code to take a look at: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators and follow the conventions laid out by the core team for creating custom validators. Otherwise, as you're finding, it's really hard to determine why someone made a design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about Angular, it's Javascript.

What you pass in the "value: this.validate" called reference.
Let say you have this function

```
function callMe(callback){
  callback(123);
}
```

And when you call it, you simply do: `callMe(console.log)`.

Similar to your example:

```
function validate(formControl){}

function ValidateData(validateFn){
  validateFn(formControl)
}
```